# How to fix: 'YAML' not installed when installing XML::Simple?

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I'm trying to install XML::Simple module however I get the following everytime.

```
cpan install XML::Simple
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Wed, 12 Mar 2014 09:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::Simple'
Running make for G/GR/GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GR/GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz ok

CPAN.pm: Going to build G/GR/GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::Simple
Writing MYMETA.yml
GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz
make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Can anyone tell me what is problem here? and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have `make` and `YAML` installed?

Comment: Looks like you don't have `make` installed. Is this on a PC, or is this on Linux? If it's Linux, you have to make sure you have the C programming tools installed. If this is Windows, and you're not using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com), use Strawberry Perl. It comes with the MIGW environment which includes `make` and `gcc` and all the libraries you need.

Comment: I'm using linux btw, and after installing make I'm able to download modules.

Comment: On a debian-based distro you could also do `sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl`.  And LeoNerd is correct don't use XML::Simple - I wrote it and I recommend XML::LibXML instead :-)

Comment: Thanks Grant! Good job on the module!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is one of those unclear error messages you get. The true problem is almost certainly that you don't have `make` installed. If this is a Debian-like box, you want to

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

or local equivalent for other OSes.

On a side note, you don't want to be using `XML::Simple` either. Try one of the many other variations on XML reading/writing from CPAN.

Answer (score 37):

Try installing `YAML` directly via `cpan`, e.g.:

```
cpan YAML
```

<sup>Source: [Re: Installing from CPAN -- YAML](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2013/03/msg122673.html)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

On the CPAN command line

```
> install YAML
```